# Controlling Step Size in 'optim' R function

Tags: r, optimization

I am using R to optimize a function using the 'optim' function. However, the true values of the variables I am optimizing over are spaced apart at least 10^-5 or so. But, as I understand it, the default step size (ie how much optim adds to each control variable to see how that changes the objective function) is of the order of 10^-8.

Is there any easy way to tell the 'optim' function to increase the step size to 10^5 or perhaps higher?

For reference my code is here:

```
Optimal <- optim(par = starting, fn =expectedSeats,
                       propensities = propsShocked, n = NumberofDistricts, 
                       shockType = "normal", shockSD = 0.1,
                       method =  "L-BFGS-B",
                       lower = rep(0,NumberofDistricts), upper = rep(1,NumberofDistricts),
                       control=list(factr =  1e12)
                       )
```

I have looked around and can't seem to figure this out. Thanks!

Comment: (1) There are two step sizes. One in the line search and one in doing the finite difference calculations. (2) The solvers assumes a continuous, smooth function. This means you really should not impose such a restriction on the step size (on either of the ones I mentioned in 1).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Can I ask for any recommendations on other optimisation algorithms in R that you think may be good for my problem. The one I posted often converges to what must be different local minima. Key characteristics of my problem: 1) large number of choice variables, 2) function being evaluated is quite slow 3) absolute bounds on choice variables (between 0 and 1). Any tips would be great! Thanks

Comment: I don't know much about your problem, so this like a doctor diagnosing a patient without examination. Expensive function evaluations often mean that there are no easy gradients (and that finite differences are very expensive). That would indicate a derivative free method may be appropriate.

Comment: More information or/and a reproducible example could help to clarify the question.

Comment: If the evaluation of the objective function is slow, my recent R package **optimParallel** https://cran.r-project.org/package=optimParallel could be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, I *believe* you can specify the step value within the `ndeps` argument of the `control=` option. According to the documentation, the default is 1e-3 (not 1e-8).